# Recommended way for implementing request response using Azure Service Bus Queue

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues

I wanted to get response from a worker role. To facilitate that I thought of using service bus where one worker role post message on a request queue read by other worker role which process it and post the message into the response queue read by the caller.

I read few blogs and find out that session Id is one of the way to achieve this. I am wondering if session id is recommended way as we need to create unique sessionId for each request. Will using unique session id per request have any performance overhead?

Is there any recommended way to achieve request-response in service bus.

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to correlate the messages, and using the Session Id is the most common way to achieve that.

Comment: Will using sessionId per request have any performance overhead esp in case where I might have millions of request being sent

Comment: I don't think so. Your message will have a few more bytes, but nothing that will compromise your performance.